# xcode Swift Save Recorded Video as mov or mp4

Tags: xcode, swift, video, save, avcapturesession

I have been having a hard time searching for a way to save a recorded video using AVCaptureSession

Here is my code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tv: UIView!
    var session:AVCaptureSession?
    var output: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var out:AVCaptureMovieFileOutput!
    var outPath:NSURL?
```

...on the view didload function

```
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let documentsURL = filemgr.URLsForDirectory(.DesktopDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
        outPath = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("temp")

        session = AVCaptureSession()
        session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow

        let camera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        var deviceInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput?

        do{
            try deviceInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
        }catch{
        }
        session?.addInput(deviceInput)
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tv.frame.width, height: self.tv.frame.height)
        tv.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        previewLayer?.frame = frame
        session?.startRunning()
```

record button action

```
        let recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate? = self
        out = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        session?.addOutput(out)
        out.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(outPath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate)
```

...stop button action

```
        out.stopRecording()
```

..and delegate functions

```
    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outPath: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!){
        print("record fin")
        return
    }
    func captureOutput(captureOutPut: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingTOOutputFileAtURL outPath: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!){
        print("record start")
        return
    }
```

Thanks for any help :)

**EDIT:** 
Here are some additional details

> There are no errors or warning in the code and the app runs just fine
>   The camera preview shows but the problem is on saving the recorded video, when the out.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(outPath, recordingDelegate: recordingDelegate) is called, it does not save any file

Comment: are your delegates called?

Comment: yup, delegate functions are being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case somebody happens to have the same problem as mine, here is the solution

add this code inside the delegate function didfinishrecording

```
    let library = PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary()
    library.performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(outPath)!
        }, completionHandler: {success, error in
            NSLog("Finished saving asset. %@", (success ? "Success." : error!))
    })
```

regards